# "As I told you" or "Like I told you"?

Tags: grammar

Which of these two sentences is correct:

> 1. Close the door as I told you.
> 2. Close the door like I told you.

Comment: What do you think? Have you done any research?

Comment: Both are rude. That's a species of "incorrect".

Comment: And yet, people do use it I am afraid...

Answer (score 1):

> Close the door like I told you

Denotes to a method

While,

> Close the door as I told you

Denotes to a circumstance.

In the first one, a specific way of closing the door has been told and the speaker is ordering it to be applied.

In the second one, the speaker is ordering the door to be closed under specific criteria the second person is being put under, where the style of closing the door is not relevant.

Comment: You should skip the *to* following *denote* and just say *denotes a method* and *denotes a circumstance*.

Comment: @tchrist thank you !